# How to find best sentence match from keywords

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

#### Problem

I want to find best sentence match from predefined list of sentences that matches user's keywords.

Common use case would be Instagram hashtags. User enters a few hashtag and he gets a suggested sentence that best encapsulates those hashtags.

#### Imagine user entered 3 hashtags:

#water #sunny #outdoor.

#### Our predefines  sentences:

*["Today is a beautiful day", "Grass is green", "Its sunny outside"].*

#### Best match:

I guess its not trivial to determine what a best match is, but it doesn't have to be most alike by words or characters, however it should summarize the keywords the best.
In our example: *"Its sunny outside"*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nlp model to get similarities between words **word2vec**
so you could compare the hastags with each words in each sentence, and find the best match

you should use tf-idf approach for weights on words, for better performance in your word-to-sentence matching

you can also use **doc2vec** but it's mostly implemented as specific case of word2vec, also I'm not sure how the hastags which can't create a proper sentence will behave